# How do I upload a file to API from form in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, api, file

I need to submit a word document/ pdf / txt file to an API.

I have a custom form in PHP that I am posting to a controller (using YII/CraftCMS but I think this is a PHP question.)

I have added my form with enctype="multipart/form-data" so it allows for files. On the controller I am able to see the file object using - `die($_FILES['my_file]);`

Now I need to get the contents of the file to send up to the API. Using `file_get_contents($_FILES['my_file]['tmp_name']);` returns loads of symbols.
ie:

```
PK\0\0\0\0ƉSKUV��\0\0\0=\0\0\0\0
```

Anyway I can parse this doc and keep its formatting?

Comment: Looks like a valid ZIP header (PK)...

Comment: If you look up how to send headers along with the data so the recieveing end knows how to deal with it, you may get an answer

Comment: Thanks both - do you mean headers in the form POST? or is this headers to change in the htaccess file?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz thanks for the response. Where would the header need to sit in this instance? Unsure why I would need a zip header on a .doc file

Comment: semi-off-topic: just for your information - if you change the name on `test.doc` file to `test.zip` you can open it like .zip file. Inside there is a folder/file structure :)